# Classification with ChatGPT: how to match bank/credit card transactions with the accounting expense category

Tags: chatgpt-api

I have a client that manages the books for hundreds of small to medium size businesses.

His staff has to go through the bank and credit card statements and match the transactions to a specific list of expense categories.

For example:

Transaction Description:

`Point Of Sale Withdrawal 160000100033 GIANT FUEL 6054        HANOVER      PAUS`

Would match to:

`Expense: Vehicle: Fuel`

I have tried a few things and not getting good results.

Done anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: You have indicated that you have tried a few things and are not getting good results, but you have not told us what things are that you have tried.  Edit your post and add some details about the things you have tried that are not getting good results.

Comment: I have been able to get pretty good results from ChatGPT (but not the API, so far) for Category+Subcategory classification of a user's goals.  When I asked ChatGPT how to 'teach' it my Categories and Subcategories, it responded with the format it wanted me to enter this info in.  After I put my Category+Subcategory infomation using the format ChatGPT told me to use, the classification worked very impressively.  I am trying to reproduce using the API but have not managed to get the same quality results so far.  I recommend trying your problem using ChatGPT first.